# jQuery popup box height positioning relative to page position

Tags: jquery, popup, resize, position, height

I currently have a pop of box that appears when clicking a link. The issue I'm having is that the link is about half way down the page and when I click the link the overlay height isn't 100% and the box appears 80px down from the top of the page. I somehow want to make the box overlay height 100% no matter what size i make the page (same as my width works) and have box so its 80px from the top of the screen relative to what I can see on the page at that point rather than when the page was first loaded.

Here's the code I have currently:

```
      //Popup dialog
      function popup(message) {

     // get the screen height and width  
     var maskHeight = $(document).height();  
     var maskWidth = $(window).width();

     // calculate the values for center alignment    
     var dialogLeft = (maskWidth/2) - ($('#dialog-box').width())/2; 

     // Set overlay to fill screen
     $("#dialog-overlay").css("width","100%").fadeIn();

     // Set dialogue box 80px from top and central
     $('#dialog-box').css({top:80, left:dialogLeft}).fadeIn();

     // display the message
     //$('#dialog-message').html(message);

     // Close button fades out overlay and message  
     $('.button').live('click',function()
     {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    $('#dialog-overlay').fadeOut();
    return false;
     });

     window.onresize = function() {
     var maskWidth = $(window).width();
          var dialogLeft = (maskWidth/2) - ($('#dialog-box').width())/2; 
     $('#dialog-box').css({top:80, left:dialogLeft});
     }

 }
```

Option I coded for the effect I was after:

```
 //Popup about location box
 function popup(message) {

// get the screen height and width  
var maskHeight = $(document).height();  
var maskWidth = $(window).width();

// calculate the values for center alignment     
var dialogLeft = (maskWidth/2) - ($('#dialog-box').width()/2); 
var dialogTop = (maskHeight/2) - ($('#dialog-box').height()/2);

// Set overlay to fill screen
$("#dialog-overlay").css("width","100%").fadeIn();
$("#dialog-overlay").css("height",maskHeight).fadeIn();

// Set dialogue box 80px from top and central
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
$('#dialog-box').css({top:80, left:dialogLeft}).delay(500).fadeIn();

// display the message
//$('#dialog-message').html(message);

// Close button fades out overlay and message   
$('.button').live('click',function()
{
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    $('#dialog-overlay').fadeOut();
    return false;
});

window.onresize = function() {
     var maskWidth = $(window).width();
     var dialogLeft = (maskWidth/2) - ($('#dialog-box').width())/2; 
     $('#dialog-box').css({top:80, left:dialogLeft});
}

 }
```

Comment: I made a work around for this if anyone else was after a similar thing, I now have the page scroll upto the top and it displays the box at 80px below the top. This way the box is always visible on the initial button click. I'll edit the code in the post to show what I changed

Comment: Can you put up a http://jsfiddle.net/ - Its free as your whole code so that we can see wats happening... thanks